# how to Read in the list of options and prices from the options.txt file into the appropriate arrays in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have created an application to book and pay for tours;

Customers can select one and only one of each of the following options for their tour:
• Coach type (3 options: 12 seater, 21 seater, 55 seater)
• Tour length (3 options: 3 days, 7 days, 10 days)

Customers may optionally select one or more of the following optional sightseeing options
for their tour:
• Bran Castle
• LiBEARty Sanctuary
• Peles Castle
• Turda Salt Mine

The application uses an array to store the three coach type options. Arrays
also store the prices per day for each coach type.

- ***i want to use an array to store the optional sightseeing tours and a separate array to store the optional sightseeing tours’ prices.***

***The optional sightseeing tours*** are dependent on the time of year the trip is taken and the
prices can change. The names and prices for these should be stored in a text file for ease
of updating and the data read into the program.

The text file should be called options.txt and should be laid out with the name of
Sightseeing Option 1 followed on the next line by the price of that option, and so on for the
four options. For example, the text file would be set out
like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DPWS.jpg)

This enables the arrays to be filled from the text file by reading in the name of each
sightseeing tour and storing it in the sightseeing tours array, then reading in its price from
the next line of the text file and storing the price in the sightseeing tours prices array

***Please assist on;***

1. Read in the list of optional sightseeing tours and prices from the
   options.txt file into the appropriate arrays
2. Fill the combo boxes or other chosen controls from the arrays. You
   should use a for loop to loop over the arrays and add the items to
   the combo boxes.
3. Write the event code to sort the sightseeing tours from least to
   most expensive. Do this before adding the tour options to checkboxes
4. Fill the checkboxes with details of the sightseeing tours

See interface below;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZxok.jpg)

See code below;

```
Public Class frmOptions
    Dim CoachType() As String = {"12 Seater", "21 Seater", "55 Seater"}   ' an array of 3 strings
    Dim CoachCost() As Integer = {150, 100, 70}   ' an array of 3 integers
    Dim TourLength() As String = {"3 days", "7 days", "10 days"}   ' an array of 3 strings
    Dim strCoachType As String
    Dim intCoachCost As Integer
    Dim intTourLength As Integer
    Dim strSightseeingOptions() As String 'Array to store selected sight seeing options
    Dim intSightseeingPrices As Integer
    Dim intTotal As Integer

    Private Function getSelectedItems()
        'Get selected Coach Type
        If rb12Seater.Checked Then
            strCoachType = "12 Seater"
            'multiply cost per day by number of coach seats
            intCoachCost = 150 * 12
        ElseIf rb21Seater.Checked Then
            strCoachType = "21 Seater"
            'multiply cost per day by number of coach seats
            intCoachCost = 100 * 21
        ElseIf rb55Seater.Checked Then
            strCoachType = "55 Seater"
            'multiply cost per day by number of coach seats
            intCoachCost = 70 * 55
        End If

        'Get selected Tour Length
        If rb3Days.Checked Then
            intTourLength = 3
        ElseIf rb7Days.Checked Then
            intTourLength = 10
        ElseIf rb10Days.Checked Then
            intTourLength = 11
        End If

        'Calculate total amount
        intTotal = intCoachCost * intTourLength


    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        btnPurchase.Enabled = False

        rb12Seater.Text = CoachType(0)
        rb21Seater.Text = CoachType(1)
        rb55Seater.Text = CoachType(2)


        rb3Days.Text = (TourLength(0))
        rb7Days.Text = TourLength(1)
        rb10Days.Text = TourLength(2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        btnPurchase.Enabled = True
        getSelectedItems()
        lblTotalCost.Text = "€" + intTotal.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub gbCoachType_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gbCoachType.Enter

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPurchase_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPurchase.Click
        btnPurchase.Enabled = False
        frmDetails.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make sure all of your code is formatted properly.  You will be more likely to get some help when you do.

Comment: `Private Function getSelectedItems()` This isn't a Function. Functions have a datatype and return a value.

Comment: Why the arrays for the radio buttons? Just set the text properties at design time.

Answer (score 0):

**Form Design:**

I did not bother to give meaningful names to the controls but you should do so.
I derived the following from your code. To simplify the code I calculated the daily rate.

- 12 seater x 150/seat per day =  1800/day
- 21 seater x 100/seat per day = 2100/day
- 55 seater x 70/seat per day =  3850/day

Set the tag property of the radio buttons in `GroupBox1` (Coach Type) to 1800, 2100, and 3850 respectively.

Set the tag property of the radio buttons in `GroupBox2` (Length of Tour) to 3, 7, an 10.

Set the `MaximumSize Width` property of Label 2 to a value that will fit on you form. The Title and Description of each option should be able to fit on the form.

Remove the text value on `Label1` and `Label2`.

**The Class:**

Instead of parallel arrays use a class for the options. This would be much easier to maintain.

```
Public Class Options

    Public Property Title As String

    Public Property Cost As Decimal 'Use a Decimal type for money

    Public Property Description As String

    'The parameterized constructor makes it easy to create an instance

    Public Sub New(t As String, c As Decimal, d As String)
        Title = t
        Cost = c
        Description = d
    End Sub

    'The ListBox will call .ToString to display your Options
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Title} - {Cost}"
    End Function
End Class
```

**In the Form:**

Notice that there are not any `Form` level variables.

```
Private Sub Tours_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Read the text file stored in bin\Debug
    '.ReadAllLine returns an array of the lines in the text file
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Options.txt")
    'Declare a list to hold the contents of the file
    Dim olst As New List(Of Options)
    'Loop through each line from the text file
    For Each line In lines
        'split each line into an array by the delimiter comma
        'the .Split method expects a Char, the small c following the string tells the compiler it is a Char
        Dim splits = line.Split(","c)
        'Create an instance of the Options class passing the values of the properties
        Dim o As New Options(splits(0), CDec(splits(1)), splits(2))
        'Add the Options instance to the List(Of Options)
        olst.Add(o)
    Next
    'Bind the ListBox to the list of Options
    'The ListBox calls .ToString() on each Option in the list (the class overrides .ToString)
    ListBox1.DataSource = olst
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub

'The Calculate button
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Find the checked RadioButton in GroupBox1
    Dim rButton1 As RadioButton = GetCheckedRadioButton(GroupBox1)
    'The Tag property was set to Seat rate X Number of seats at design time
    Dim Total As Decimal = CDec(rButton1.Tag)
    'The Tag property was set to the number of days at design time
    Dim rButton2 As RadioButton = GetCheckedRadioButton(GroupBox2)
    'Multiply Total by number of days
    Total *= CDec(rButton2.Tag)
    'Add costs of optional tours
    For Each item As Options In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        Total += item.Cost
    Next
    Label1.Text = "$" & Total.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label2.Text = ""
    For Each item As Options In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        Label2.Text &= $"{item.Title}{Environment.NewLine}{item.Description}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}"
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetCheckedRadioButton(Container As Control) As RadioButton
    'This is a bit of LINQ magic. It can be handy in many situations. Sometimes the Container is a Form which is, indeed, a Control!
    Dim rButton As RadioButton = Container.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Return rButton
End Function
```

This really isn't as much code as it looks like because of the extensive comments.